# How to manage access rights for rocket.chat, so that all users are not visible to everyone?

Tags: meteor, rocket.chat

I am using Rocket.chat as part of a website, where users from different organizations can log in and chat with their colleagues.

How to configure rocket.chat so that users from different organizations cannot see each other?

For example, can I define a user hierarchy and also a custom permission (like: can-see-other-organization) in Rocket.chat?

Comment: Did you manage to get it?

Answer (score 0):

Also interested in this question. 
One of solutions found: to proxy and filter requests. 
Its not the best solution, but no one else found for now.